# What is the phonetic component of 斜?

Tags: kanji, onyomi

Again, during my kanji reviews, I encountered 斜. Remembering its kunyomi is not difficult because it's the most common word associated with this kanji (at least based on my reviews); its onyomi, however, always slips my mind.

I checked what kind of kanji 斜 is and it said that it's 形声. I assume that the right component is the phonetic component, but I checked the kanjis with 斗 and none of them have シャ as an onyomi.

Is this a case similar to 侮辱、後悔、海外 where the first kanji 侮 somehow changed its sound in Chinese before being imported to Japanese?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *kanji* has changed its sound long before importation into Japanese.

---

「[斜]{しゃ}」 ([Zhengzhang OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Zhengzhang_(1981%E2%80%931995)): **/*lja/**, *to scoop/ladle*) is comprised of semantic [「斗」 (*picture of a ladle*](http://chinese-linguipedia.org/search_source_inner.html?word=%E6%96%97) > *unit of measure for liquids*) and phonetic 「[余]{よ}」 (**/*la/**). You can take the modern meaning, *slanted*, to be a [phonetic loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Rebus_(phonetic_loan)_characters).

<sub>*The *unit of measure for liquids* might also be seen with the *kanji* 「升」. Indeed, [「升」 was originally 「斗」 with dots added](http://chinese-linguipedia.org/search_source_inner.html?word=%E5%8D%87), indicating that the ladle was full of liquid.</sub>

---

Putting aside characters directly containing 「[余]{よ}」 (e.g. [途]{と}, [除]{じょ}), the exact shape 「余」 has undergone quite a few sound shifts and graphical corruptions in other *kanji*. You might find some more correspondences with 「[斜]{しゃ}」 in those changes; even though 「[余]{よ}」 itself appears to be rather far phonologically from 「[斜]{しゃ}」, the characters containing variants of 「余」 may still be fairly close in sound to 「斜」.

Observe the [glyph evolution of 「余」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=477), and then compare:

- 「余」 is the bottom component of 「[茶]{ちゃ}」, which was originally written as 「荼」.
- 「余」 was originally the [top component of 「[舍]{しゃ}」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1062) (*Shinjitai*: 「舎」).
- 「余」 is sometimes corrupted into 「佘」 to produce a phonetic indicator 「[示]{し}」. In rare circumstances, you might come across a character containing 「佘」; their *on'yomi* would be something like [「[賒]{しゃ}」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=3687).

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. It's a relief to know that 斜 is a phonetic loan, so I don't have to try to extract its meaning from the kanji. It's also nice to know that 捨 and 舎 share a common component with 斜.